# Grep - Must not contain "//" but must contain "error_log" or "console.log"

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to create a simple regex to loop through strings to find either "error_log" or "console.log" but must not be commented out (begin with // on line), I've tried:

`^(?!.*(\/\/)).*(error_log|console.log).*$` (Failed)

`(?!\/\/).*error_log\(.*\)\;$` (Picked up every error_log)

`^(?!.*\/\/).*error_log.*\;` (Failed)

What am I doing wrong? Sample data:

`// error_log("This shouldn't be picked up by regex");`

`error_log("this should be picked up by regex");`

Comment: Use [^\/]{2} in the start of the regex, [example](https://regex101.com/r/93t4oN/1)

Comment: show your `grep --version` output

Comment: Simple thing is to just pipe grep to grep.  `grep 'error_log|console\.log' file | grep -v '^\/\/'`